# Воспроизведение звука с Youtube трансляций

Tags: python, pyqt, youtube, qgraphicsview, qwebengineview

Нужно реализовать воспроизведение звука с трансляции на **`Youtube`** в *`фоновом`* режиме.

То есть без видео, в самом приложении (на *PyQt5*, если что). 
Эдакое радио.

Куда копать, в какие библиотеки?

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант. В верхнем левом углу есть типа кнопки включить/выключить.
Нажимаем и слушаем. То что надо вставить в ваш интерфейс - отмечено `# +++`.

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings


def create_pixmap(size):
    pixmap = QPixmap(size)
    pixmap.fill(QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3)))
    return pixmap


class VariantAnimation(QVariantAnimation):
    def updateCurrentValue(self, value):
        pass


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MyEngineView(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, ):
        super(MyEngineView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(26, 26)
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled, True)
        self.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(lambda request: request.accept())
        baseUrl = "local"
        htmlString = """
            <iframe width="10" height="10" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/L0MK7qz13bU?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        """
        self.setHtml(htmlString, QUrl(baseUrl))
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        view = QGraphicsView(scene)
        parent_item = scene.addPixmap(create_pixmap(QSize(150, 150)))
        parent_item.setTransformOriginPoint(parent_item.boundingRect().center())
        parent_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        child_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(create_pixmap(QSize(70, 70)))
        child_item.setParentItem(parent_item)
        child_item.setTransformOriginPoint(child_item.boundingRect().center()) 
        child_item.setOffset(40, 40)                       

        self.animation = VariantAnimation(
            startValue=0, endValue=360, duration=2000, loopCount=-1
        )
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(parent_item.setRotation)
        self.animation.start()
        self.setCentralWidget(view)

        self.browser = MyEngineView(self)                                          # +++
        self.browser.move(1, 1)                                                    # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('Воспроизведение звука с youtube трансляций')
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @type49 ответ полезный ?

Comment: Безусловно, однако именно трансляции, которые мне нужны не воспроизводит, только видео. Насколько я понял, этот браузер не поддерживает HTML5.