# Можно ли по ссылке с ютуба воспроизвести аудио через Python

Tags: python, файлы, аудио, youtube

Есть ссылка на видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EErSKhC0CZs. **Цель** - чтобы при запуске программы **заиграла песня, но не скачивался файл**. Типо музыкальных ботов в дискорде. Реализация через **Python**. *Пробовал скачивать файл, через youtube_dl, но если стрим, то аудио долго будет грузиться и нельзя будет слушать, поэтому хотелось бы без скачивания файла.* Или скачивать файл, но чтобы он уже был доступен для воспроизведения. То есть, файл скачивается и в это же время его можно слушать. (Если, что использую windows 10)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122013/%d0%92%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-youtube-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9 ?

Comment: А можно вытащить, чтобы не было визуала?